# Twilio Conference statusCallback sends GET request instead of POST request

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to create a conference on inbound voice call.

I have the following TwiML that should trigger a `POST` request from twilio for the following events `start,end` I already specifed the **statusCallbackMethod** to `POST` but twilio keeps sending `GET` request to the **statusCallback**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Conference 
startConferenceOnEnter="true" 
endConferenceOnExit="true" participantLabel="WKxxx" 
statusCallbackEvent="start,end" 
statusCallback="http://xxx" 
statusCallbackMethod="POST">CAxxx</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

I already set the webhooks to `POST` in the [Active phone numbers Webhooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wEa9.png)

I 'am expecting a `POST` request in `statusCallback` but I keep getting `GET`  request.

Comment: I see you have used correct steps as per Twilio's documentation, the issue might lie in server configuration, network issues, or possibly a bug or temporary issue on Twilio's side. kindly cross check this or contact Twilio support